# Sitecore xDB exception and session terminates

Tags: xdb, session-state

We are using Sitecore 8.2 in the following configuration:

1 CM instance

2 CD instances on load balancer

Sitecore analytics is enabled

We have not identified the contacts

Analytics.cluster is set to the site URL http://abc.com/ on CD server while default value is present on CM server

We are getting the following in logs on CD server:

> ERROR Cannot finish Analytics page tracking Exception:
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Exceptions.ContactLockException Message: Failed to
>   extend contact lease for contact cc5dd459-3ec0-47c3-a175-8ff4082dbd62
>   Source: Sitecore.Analytics    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.SaveAndReleaseContact(Contact
>   contact)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EndAnalytics.ReleaseContact.Process(PipelineArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EndAnalytics.EndAnalyticsPipeline.Run()
>   at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EndAnalytics.Process(HttpRequestArgs
>   args)

My queries are the following:

1. Is there something wrong with my configuration, other than disabling Sitecore Analytics?
2. Can this issue lead to abrupt session end on the website?

Comment: @Marek We are getting this in log on CD server. The issue you have referred is for CM server.

Comment: @JustDolt my close vote is retracted

Comment: You will want to make sure that the Analytics.ClusterName is also abc.com on the CM server.  This message on the CD's means that during the Session End event, it is trying to save the contact to xDB and can't because something else has the contact locked.  All Sitecore servers should use the same cluster name. Additionally, you will also want to make sure that the clustername on all servers is a resolvable domain that resolves to a CD cluster.

Comment: @PeteNavarra The cluster name on CD servers is resolvable from all servers. I will update the same for CM server.

Comment: @PeterNavrra Please provide it as answer, so I can mark it the same.